# Prove, there exists z, so $|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k| \geq \sqrt{\sum_{k=0} ^n |a_k|}, |z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to prove, that there exists $z$, that expression is valid for z with |z|=1:
$$
|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k| \geq \sqrt{\sum_{k=0} ^n |a_k|^2}
$$
Note that $a_0, a_1, ... , a_n \in \mathbb{C} $.

I don't really know how to start. First I tried to solve only for real $a_k$, not complex, and than expressed, $z$ as $e^{i\phi}$, I than expressed left side of equation as $|a_0+a_1 e^{i\phi}+ a_2 e^{2i\phi} + ... +a_n e^{ni\phi}|$, than I tried to use triangle inequality, but I dont know, how this is usefull.

Comment: something wrong there. Take $f(z) = \frac z4$ and then this would mean there must be $|z| = 1$ and $|z|\geq 2.$

Comment: What do u mean with $f(z)$? Where should I put it?

Comment: presumably, it is $\sqrt{\sum_{k=0} ^n |a_k|^2}$ since Parseval gives the result timmediately - as it stands choosing $a_1=1/4, a_k =0, k \ne 1$ gives a contradiction as noted

Comment: There was also a hint included in the exercises, which says, I should use integration.

Comment: @Conrad tnx, it was typo, I corrected

Comment: $1/(2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{it})|^2dt=\sum_{k=0} ^n |a_k|^2$ so conclude - (where $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$)

Comment: @Conrad What form of Parseval's identity is that?

Comment: Just the standard form but for a trigonometric polynomial $\sum_{ 0 \le k \le n} a_ke^{ikt}$; integrating $|f|^2$ on the unit circle gives $\sum_{k=0} ^n |a_k|^2$ by orthogonality and then we must have the value at a point $\ge$ that as otherwise the integral is too small